# Javascript events not firing on elements in a bootstrap modal

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a web app that uses a virtual keypad to input data into input boxes.
HTML CODE:

```
<form class="form-price">
    <input type="text" class="form-control keypad-line" id="price-value" onfocus="blur()"/>
    <div class="keypad-line">
        <a data-target="#price-value" class="btn btn-default keypad-btn value-key">7</a> 
        <a data-target="#price-value" class="btn btn-default keypad-btn value-key">8</a> 
        <a data-target="#price-value" class="btn btn-default keypad-btn value-key">9</a>
    </div>
    <div class="keypad-line">
        <a data-target="#price-value" class="btn btn-default keypad-btn value-key">4</a> 
        <a data-target="#price-value" class="btn btn-default keypad-btn value-key">5</a> 
        <a data-target="#price-value" class="btn btn-default keypad-btn value-key">6</a>
    </div>
    <div class="keypad-line">
        <a data-target="#price-value" class="btn btn-default keypad-btn value-key">1</a> 
        <a data-target="#price-value" class="btn btn-default keypad-btn value-key">2</a> 
        <a data-target="#price-value" class="btn btn-default keypad-btn value-key">3</a>
    </div>
    <div class="keypad-line">
        <a data-target="#price-value" class="btn btn-danger keypad-btn delete-key">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-left"></span>
        </a> 
        <a data-target="#price-value" class="btn btn-default keypad-btn value-key">0</a> 
        <a data-target="#price-value" class="btn btn-default keypad-btn value-key">.</a>
    </div>
</form>
```

JAVASCRIPT:

```
$(function(){
    $(".value-key").click(function(){
        alert("hit");
        var inputTarget = $(this).data("target");
        $(inputTarget).val($(inputTarget).val() + $(this).html());
    });
    $(".delete-key").click(function(){
        var inputTarget = $(this).data("target");
        $(inputTarget).val($(inputTarget).val().substr(0,$(inputTarget).val().length-1));
    });
    $(".debug-key").click(function(){
        var inputTarget = $(this).data("target");
        alert($(inputTarget).val());
    });
});
```

This keypad is in use and fully functional in many places within my code.
The issue I am having is if I put the keypad in a Bootstrap Modal the click events in my javascript do not go off.
I don't know what is causing this, I have a javascript library (bootbox.js) that builds the modal and adds it to the bottom of the html body.
I have double checked that the code in the modal is correct and it works if copied out of the modal.
Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: I'm guessing the modal is dynamic and that you need delegated event handlers, and there should be a million answers to how to use delegated event handlers in jQuery, so just search.

Comment: $("body").on("click", ".value-key", function(){

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Upon some researcher into how dynamic content works and how js works I added a call to my keypad.js file above the keypad in the dynamic modal constructor so that the elements are initialized when the function is created.

Thank you everyone for pointing me in the right direction.

Answer (score 3):

It seems you init this function before Bootstrap Modal element created, may be you can try delegate click events, it should be working.

Such as:

```
$('body').on('click', '.value-key', function() {
  // some code here
});
```